# Generators and electric motors

Tags: electrical-engineering

In a diesel generator, instead of using diesel engine can we use an electric engine and connect the motor and generator to the battery?
will this make it an infinitely moving system or will the electricity get reduced due to resistence?
can we connect the generator to another generator and thus increase the energy generation. Will this make it an infinitely running system.[my knowladge of physics is very less, please dont laugh!!]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The electric motor is not 100% efficient in converting electrical power to mechanical power nor is the electric generator 100% efficient in converting mechanical power to electrical power nor is the battery 100% efficient in storing electrical energy as chemical energy or in releasing that stored energy.

In other words, there is a loss at each step of power conversion.

The power supplied by the battery to the motor will be greater than the mechanical power developed by the motor and that will be greater than the electrical power developed by the the generator.

Thus, the answer is no, the stored energy in the battery will eventually be depleted and the motor will stop.

Comment: @Shashank, generators don't *produce* energy, they *convert* energy and, again, they don't convert with 100% efficiency.

Comment: sorry wanted to say electricity instead of energy.... but the electricity wasted could be equal to the electricity produced???? couldn't it???